# Rosemary plant issue

Tags: houseplants, plant-health

My rosemary cutting had been growing normally for past few month but since last week, the new grown leaves are not as green as before and I have noticed that the young leaves are turning brown. I would like to know what is happening to my plant? I suspect there might be a fungi infection but it seems like the browned spots only happens to the new leaves. What can I do to deal with this problem?

[image: Browned young leaves]

[image: Color difference between old(lower) and new(taller) leaves][image: Root system]

Comment: Are you intending to transplant into a pot with soil  now it has roots, or were you  wanting to continue keeping it in water? What is the orange  'stick' in the water  in the final  photo?

Comment: The orange stick is just for holding up the cutting because the jar was too tall, and I planned on keeping it grow in water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep growing the Rosemary in water, you need to use a hydroponic system, which provides nutrition and deters infection, though Rosemary is more prone to botrytis when grown in this way; whilst Rosemary will root in water, it's  usual for it then to be potted up into soil. Information on growing Rosemary hydroponically here https://gardeningtips.in/growing-rosemary-hydroponically-a-full-guide

UPDATE:

I suggest you plant it in new potting soil in a relatively small pot with drainage holes asap. Water in well,allow  to drain down freely, and water ongoing when the surface of the soil feels dry (but not so dry it's shrunken from  the sides of the pot),emptying out any outer tray or pot 30 minutes later. After you've potted it up, cut the stem back by a third to a half (see final sentence), to encourage new growth from the base. Hopefully,this will mean, although the browning leaves may fall (and when they do, remove them from the soil, don't leave them sitting on the top) your cutting will grow on healthily. The signs are hopeful, because there is evidence of new side shoots developing above the browning parts - cut back to just above a part with new side shoots.

As it gets bigger, you will need to move it into a larger pot, once it's formed a good root system in the soil.

Comment: I see, but is the plant going to die due to this browning problem? And if so can planting it in soil solves the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Great suggestions. Thanks for the replies.